# Python Leave Loop Early

Tags: python, loops

How do I leave a loop early in python?

```
for a in b:
    if criteria in list1:
        print "oh no"
        #Force loop i.e. force next iteration without going on
    someList.append(a)
```

Also, in java you can `break` out of a loop, is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It hides the builtin.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`continue` and `break` is what you want. Python works identically to Java/C++ in this regard.

Comment: Random curiosity; are you "Max_aka_NOBODY" from the Bethesda Forums? You share the same avatar which was why I was wondering.

Answer (score 26):

Firstly, bear in mind it might be possible to do what you want with a list comprehension.  So you might be able to use something like:

```
somelist = [a for a in b if not a.criteria in otherlist]
```

If you want to leave a loop early in Python you can use `break`, just like in Java.

```
>>> for x in xrange(1,6):
...     print x
...     if x == 2:
...         break
...
1
2
```

If you want to start the next iteration of the loop early you use `continue`, again just as you would in Java.

```
>>> for x in xrange(1,6):
...     if x == 2:
...         continue
...     print x
...
1
3
4
5
```

[Here's the documentation for `break` and `continue`.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html)  This also covers `else` clauses for loops, which aren't run when you `break`.

Answer (score 5):

`continue` and `break` work exactly like in other programming languages, except that you cannot `break` to a label (as you can in Java, for example). That means you can only break *one* loop at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`break`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) and `continue`.