# End a loop early in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Leave Loop Early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184287/python-leave-loop-early)

So, I have a loop in python where I need it to take a number from another number until it is negative, and have a message every time it subtracts. The problem is, if the variable fits the first condition, it will go through the entire loop fitting the conditions and printing the message every time.

```
sb = bosshp12 - final
if sb <= 0:
    print( 'You need to do 1 second of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
sb - final
if sb <= 0:
    print( 'You need to do 2 seconds of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
```

So, if the number is already `< 0` at the first if statement, it will still pass through. I want the loop to break after `sb <= 0`

Comment: I don't see any loop in your example...

Comment: no loop also `sb - final` does nothing, you want `sb = sb -final` or shortened: `sb -= final`

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but you should really [read the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: What can I use then to set it up so that a number is subtracted and a message is displayed until it's <= 0?

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, all that code is under a while loop, you can just use the break statement

```
sb = bosshp12 - final
    if sb <= 0:
            print( 'You need to do 1 second of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
            break
    sb - final
    if sb <= 0:
            print( 'You need to do 2 seconds of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
```

OH It also seems an elif statement can fit your need?

```
sb = bosshp12 - final
        if sb <= 0:
                print( 'You need to do 1 second of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
        sb - final
        elif sb <= 0:
                print( 'You need to do 2 seconds of damage to get a 4% Soulbound. ' )
```

That way, if sb <=0 is True on the first check, the second one won't be checked.

Comment: If I tab the first if over, it says unexpected indent. It also said invalid syntax for the elif.

Comment: You're using a `elif` with the same condition?