# Number guessing game

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import random 
def guess_number():
    numb = random.randrange (10) +1
    guessestaken = 0
    guess = input("whats your number")
    while (guess != numb):
            if (guess > numb):
                print "too low"
            elif(guess < numb):
                print "too high"

            else:
                input("whats your next numb")
                tries += 1
```

I am making a number guessing game with range 1 to 10  and I need help on getting the loop to stop. when I guess the number it keeps going

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Leave Loop Early](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184287/python-leave-loop-early)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you're trying to do:

```
import random 

guessesTaken = 0
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
     print('Take a guess.\n')
     guess = input()
     guess = int(guess)
     guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
     if guess < number:
         print('Your guess is too low.')
     if guess > number:
         print('Your guess is too high.')
     if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
     guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
     print('Good job, You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reassign `guess` within the loop, so the truth value of `guess != numb` never changes. Put `guess =` before the `input()` call within the loop, or restructure it to a `while True: ... break` layout. Also, you only give the user another chance to guess the number if they get it exactly correct. Read through your code slowly and try to follow along with what the interpreter is doing.