# How do I exit a while loop?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that prompts the user to input some information to output the pay amount. After displaying the amount, the program asks the user whether the user wants to repeat it using the while loop. After the definition of the program that calculates the pay amount, there is a while loop to repeat the questions for the inputs. The problem is that I cannot find a way to exit the loop.
Here is what I have so far:

```py
def CalPay(hrs,rate):
    print('Please enter number of hours worked for this week:', hrs)
    print('What is hourly rate?', rate)
    try:
        hrs = float(hrs)
    except: 
        print('You entered wrong information for hours.')
        return
    try:
        rate=float(rate)
    except:
        print('You entered wrong rate information.')
        return
    if hrs < 0:
        print('You entered wrong information for hours.')
    elif rate < 0:
        print('You entered wrong rate information.')
    else:
        if hrs > 60:
            pay=((hrs-60)*2*rate)+(20*rate*1.5)+(rate*40)
            print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
        elif hrs > 40:
            pay=((hrs-40)*1.5*rate)+(rate*40)
            print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
        else:
            pay=rate*hrs
            print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
    repeat=input('Do you want another pay calculation?(y or n)')
    while repeat == 'y' or 'Y':
        while True:
            try:
                hrs = float(input('Please enter number of hours worked for this week:'))
            except: 
                print('You entered wrong information for hours.')
                continue
            else:
                break
        while True:
            try:
                rate=float(input('What is hourly rate?'))
            except:
                print('You entered wrong rate information.')
                continue
            else:
                break
        if hrs < 0:
            print('You entered wrong information for hours.')
        elif rate < 0:
            print('You entered wrong rate information.')
        else:
            if hrs > 60:
                pay=((hrs-60)*2*rate)+(20*rate*1.5)+(rate*40)
                print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
            elif hrs > 40:
                pay=((hrs-40)*1.5*rate)+(rate*40)
                print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
            else:
                pay=rate*hrs
                print('Your pay for this week is:', '$'+str(pay))
        repeat=input('Do you want another pay calculation?(y or n)')
    print('Good Bye!')
```

Comment: use break  statement

Comment: or use return in function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Leave Loop Early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184287/python-leave-loop-early)

Comment: I already tried using break, but the still continues.

Comment: Add a plain python tag please

Comment: @SamuelLau. No it doesn't. You just didn't use `break` carefully.

Comment: add the break inside the try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is, every time after calculation it is asking you question "'Do you want another pay calculation?(y or n)'" and if you answer n, still execution is going inside loop.

you are using below condition in while

```
while repeat == 'y' or 'Y':    #this is wrong
```

when you write above condition it actually resolves to

```
while (repeat == 'y') or ('Y'):
```

here first condition is false but 2nd is true. So execution will go inside while.

Instead use 'in' keyword as below.

```
while repeat in ['y', 'Y']:    #I will prefer this.
```

or

```
while repeat == 'y' or repeat=='Y':
```

or

```
while repeat == ('y' or 'Y'):
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I just tried what you recommended, and it worked. Do you mind explaining why my condition in while is wrong? I thought that means the same as what you recommended.

Comment: check my post edit. Mark it as answer if it make sense to you. or ask a question, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested while loops. You'll need to break out of both of them.