# how do I loop only 2 times?

Tags: python

```py
datas1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
datas2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
for (a, b) in zip(datas1, datas2):
    print(a, b)
```

how do I loop only 2 times instead of looping through all existing list?

Comment: `if` statement + `break` statement with a counter?  why loop only twice? [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [python-leave-loop-early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184287/python-leave-loop-early)

Comment: `for a, b, _ in zip(datas1, datas2, (1, 2)):`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) to avoid iterating over all values:

```
from itertools import islice

datas1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
datas2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

for (a, b) in islice(zip(datas1, datas2), 2):
    print(a, b)
```

Giving you:

```
1 6
2 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Just.... Iterate... Twice:

```
for i in range(2):
    print(datas1[i], datas2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
for num, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(data1,data2)):
    if num == 2:
       break
    print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension should do what you are looking for:

`[x for x in zip(a, b)][:2]`

Comment: this doesn't really loop two times only, it loops for all a and b then returns only the first two results, which is wasteful for large `a,b`, instead consider slicing `a` and `b` to only 2 elements.

Answer (score -1):

Slice one of the lists:

```
datas1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
datas2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
for (a, b) in zip(datas1[:2], datas2):
    print(a, b)
```